# Implement user authentication against remote DB with a Web Service

Tags: ios, web-services, authentication, service, web

I'm just starting reasearch about the best way to implement user authentication within my soon-to-be app.

This is what I have so far:

- A desktop (Windows) application on a remote server.  That application is accessed locally with a browser (it has a web console and MS SQL Server to store everything).
- The application is used with local credendials stored in the DB.

This is what I'd like to accompllish:

- Provide access to some information on that SQL Server DB from my app.  That access of course must be granted once a user has id himself with valid credentials.

This is what I know so far:

- How to create my PHP web service and query info from a DB using JSON.
- How to work with AFNetworking libraries to retrieve information.
- How to display that info on the app.

What I don't know is which could be the best method to implement user authentication from iOS.  Should I send username and password? Should I send some hash? Is there a way to secure the handshake?

I'd for sure appreciate any advise, tip, or recommendation you have from previous experience.

I don't want to just implement it but instead I want to do it as good as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There have been books written on this, so any answer given here is necessary incomplete. So, I'll give you an outline of the simplest thing that actually works. The bare minimum for securing a service like this is to use HTTP Basic Authentication (supported natively by both AFNetworking and PHP) secured by SSL/TLS.

Basic Authentication is a way of hashing (not encrypting) credentials in a standard way and sending them as one of the headers in your request (`Authorization: Basic <Base64-encoded concatenated credentials>`). AFNetworking supports this as part of its `AFHTTPClient` class (see the `-setAuthorizationHeaderWithUsername:password:` method). PHP parses the authentication header into a pair of server variables (`$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']` and `$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']`). From here, you just check the username/password combination against your user database and allow or forbid access to the resource.

The reason it's crucial to pair this technique with HTTPS is that the credential hash is easily reversible; you're basically sending the password in the clear, so it can be grabbed by anyone listening to your traffic. Setting up a certificate and sending your requests over the secure channel prevents this type of vulnerability.

If you want to be a little more sophisticated, two-legged OAuth is also a viable choice for this scenario.